# Como mostrar casas decimais apenas quando elas existirem?

Tags: query, select, sql-server-2005

Como eu poderia fazer para que no meu select os números aparecessem sem casa decimal quando forem 00 e aparecessem as casas decimais quando forem diferentes de zero.

Exemplo: tenho 5 números retornando assim: 16,00 ; 10,00 ; 3,14 ; 5,00 ; 13,45.
Como faço para eles retornarem dessa forma: 16 ; 10 ; 3,14; 5 ; 13,45.

Comment: Pode converter para varchar?

Comment: Com que tipo de dados esses números estão gravados no banco?

Comment: Os números estão gravados como decimais.

Comment: Acho que não teria problema converter para varchar, sendo que o resultado na consulta for o que eu preciso.

Comment: No sql-server-2005 não tem similar a SELECT Replace(COLUNA, ',00', '') AS P FROM TABELA